# How to force detecting specific intent regardless what is user input in dialogflow v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I would like to force detecting an intent so whatever user input is to redirect to specific intent.

Currently I am trying to achieve this using the following code by passing context name:

```
 const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          text: query,
          languageCode: 'en-US',
        },
      },
      queryParams: {
      contexts: [
          {
            "name": "projects/xxx/agent/sessions/yyy/contexts/question-followup",
            "lifespanCount": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    };
```

But it seems that it detects the intent by user input and not the context I have given!

Any idea on how to achieve such thing?

Comment: Can you update the question to include a screen shot of the Intent you think should be matched and some text that you think should match it? Or some more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Prisoner let's say I have two Intents A and B, on the intent A i have some training like Hello, Hi, Greetings while on the intent B i have nothing declared as trainings but I have declared a incoming context lets call it question-follow-up as input, so I would like when user says whatever like for example "I have some question to ask" normally in my case this would go to Default Fallback, unknown input, but what I would want is to attach as a parameter or something so when there is anything else go to intent B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty vague what you're trying to do, but you have a few approaches, I think.

**Fallback Intent with Context**

You can create multiple Fallback Intents in the system, the trick is that each should have different Contexts as requires input contexts. In these cases, if there is no match to the text input, it will find a Fallback that has all of its input contexts set.

**Use the `@sys:any` Entity**

An empty training phrase literally means "say nothing", so just having one with a matching Context isn't enough. Instead, you can set the training phrase to just a parameter with a `@sys:any` Entity.

This is probably the least likely to actually do what you want, but could be useful if there are components of the phrase you do want to capture.

**Send an Event**

Since you're calling Dialogflow using the API, if you want to force a particular Intent, you can send an Event instead of sending text and it will match the Intent that has that Event set.. The Event tends to be given priority over other rules to determine which Intent to call.

The message you'd send to `detectIntent` with [event data](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#eventinput) might look something like this:

```
 const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        event: {
          name: 'event_personal_MINE',
          parameters: {
            whatever: 'value'
          },
          languageCode: 'en-US',
        },
      },
    };
```

(The parameters are optional)

Comment: third option looks much simpler, gotta give a try! thanx!

Comment: Hope it helps! (As always, if it does, accepting and/or upvoting the answer is appreciated.)

Comment: Surely, thnx, I am trying it!

Comment: how do I send an event instead of a text?

Comment: I knew you were going to ask that. Updated answer.

Comment: last option i tried and worked it forces to triger specific intent, thanks, but parameters are not visible... maybe i should look the documentation for that!

Comment: I dont know for what reason but the intent detection just stopped working and I can no longer force an intent trigger by setting event name.... quite strange! I am still using the same code you wrote on ur answer and set the event to the intent!

Comment: turns out the first method is easier and cleanest one!